# form fields hidden by keyboard | not pushing up?

Tags: flutter

I am building a login page, and when the user selects one of the fields, the field is hidden by the keyboard.

Is there an unobtrusive way to push up the entire page so that the form fields show while the user is typing? I saw a bunch of resources online, and everyone seems to just hash different items together, as there is no easy way to do so.

Has flutter evolved so that there is a simple way to do so?

```
   class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        SingleChildScrollView(
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              "assets/Login_Photo.jpg",
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(45.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Login',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 35,
                        fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0),
                      child: Row(
                        // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextFormField(
                              decoration:
                                  InputDecoration(hintText: "Email Address"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0),
                      child: Row(
                        // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Password"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        OutlineButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => Login()));
                          },
                          child: Text('Login'),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Color(0xff33333D),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
          ],
        ));
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: The only consistent way I've been able to do it is to wrap the column in a SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: @ScottGodfrey Did not seem to work... Can you please review the code? I have updated to show the change

Comment: You should enable `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` (Have a look [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomInset.html)). Also remove `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` as it's deprecated.

Comment: Why did you wrap the column in the in the SingleChildScrollView?  And, you can scroll up to view the hidden text fields.